# How to make saved object immediately appear in a ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**JS:**

```
  $scope.addPano = function () {
      var Pano = AV.Object.extend("Panorama"),
      pano = new Pano()

      var json = {
        'name': 'test3',
        'index': 0,
        'Type': 'real',
        'version': 0,
        'buildingCode': $scope.buildingId
      }

      pano.save(json, {
    success: function(object) {
      console.log('PANO: ', object)
      $scope.building.pano.push(json)
      $scope.$digest()
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
      console.log('Failed to create new object, with error message: ' + error.message);
    }
      })
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="pano in building.pano">
  <p><strong>{{pano.name}}</strong></p>
  <div ng-repeat="panodata in pano.panoData">
    <p>{{panodata.name}}</p>
  </div> <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:;" ng-click="addPanodata(pano.objectId)">Add panodata</a> </div> <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="javascript:;" ng-click="addPano()">Add pano</a>
</div>
```

Right now the only way to make it appear is with:

```
      $scope.building.pano.push(json)
      $scope.$digest()
```

I thought Angular did this automatically?

Comment: `$scope.$digest()` shouldn't be necessary in this situation.  In fact, it's generally a bad idea to call `$digest()` directly.  It makes sense that you would have to push the new item into the local array, however....

Comment: @alexchenco, why you guys still use angular 1???? angular 2 is coming in beta!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this type But In your code  either you reload data after save method calling successfully then you can easily appear easily..

```js
function myctrl($scope){
  $scope.data =[{name:'abc'}];
  
  $scope.pushdata = function(name){
    $scope.data.push({name});
    $scope.name ='';
    
  }
}
```

```html
<html ng-app=''>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-controller='myctrl'>
      <input type='text' name='name' ng-model='name'/>
    <button name='clickme' type=submit ng-click='pushdata(name)'>save</button>
    <div ng-repeat='obj in data'>
      {{obj.name}}
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The official way to do this is to write your `pano` service to support angular. So where you call the success callback in the service:

```
.factory('pano', function() {
  return {
    save: function(x, options) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        options.success(123);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
});
```

You should wrap it in a $scope.$apply so angular has an opportunity to run dirty-checking:

```
.factory('pano', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    save: function(x, options) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          options.success(123);
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
});
```

The same applies for the error handling callback.

Note: The builtin angular services, like `$http`, `$q`, `$timeout` do this automatically.